# How write script to print uncomment line

Tags: scripting

I have a very long config file with hardly comment and uncomment line
Now I want to print out lines with uncomment

```
# LOCAL PATHNAME INFORMATION
#
# The queue_directory specifies the location of the Postfix queue.
# This is also the root directory of Postfix daemons that run chrooted.
# See the files in examples/chroot-setup for setting up Postfix chroot
# environments on different UNIX systems.
#
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix

# The command_directory parameter specifies the location of all
# postXXX commands.
#
command_directory = /usr/sbin
```

I want the output is lines with no comment

> queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
>
> command_directory = /usr/sbin

Comment: can you give an example of such a line?

Comment: Please clarify, I'm having trouble parsing your sentences.

Comment: example the main.cf config file of Postfix MTA
# LOCAL PATHNAME INFORMATION
#
# The queue_directory specifies the location of the Postfix queue.
# This is also the root directory of Postfix daemons that run chrooted.
# See the files in examples/chroot-setup for setting up Postfix chroot
# environments on different UNIX systems.
#
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix

# The command_directory parameter specifies the location of all
# postXXX commands.
#
command_directory = /usr/sbin
#

=> I want the line with no comment

Comment: @billyduc, as your comments below show, a *script* wasn't needed, a *command* is enough. And it's a good idea to give an idea of the intended Operating System and scripting language (if that's what you want).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
egrep -a -v '^[[:space:]]*#' config_file | egrep -a '[[:print:]]' | less
```

will account for spaces before the #. Pipe it to less and you can view it easily

replace config_file with $1 and put the line in /usr/local/bin/cless and chmod it +x and you have nice little script whenever you need it.

```
cless config_file
```

Comment: Your script work great !

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that commented lines begin with "#" in the first position:

```
grep -v '^#' config_file
```

will print all the lines that do not begin with "#" in the file "config_file".

Comment: your script also work and easy to remember ... thank you